# Loop through values and filter with them VBA - I need to know how to

Tags: excel, vba

The below is just creating the email only for the first value found in the Rawdata or the RemoveDup Sheet :(

I've tried the for each as mentioned below, but its still not working.

Please help

```
Sub Macro1()

     Sheets("RawData").Select
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "DupRemoved"
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$1000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    Dim Cll As Range
    For Each Cll In Selection
    If Cll.Value < 0 Then
    Cll.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Opp").Value




        Worksheets("FilteredData").Range("$A$2:$S$1224").Cells.ClearContents
        Sheets("RawData").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$1224").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Opp").Value
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Sheets("FilteredData").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("Mail").Select
           ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$1224").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Opp").Value
    Sheets("RawData").Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        Sheets("Home").Select

        End If

        Next Cll

        Call Macro2



      End Sub
```

Comment: We will need more info!! " its still not working" does not tell us anything!!  We need 1) Input sample from RawData that contains some duplicates,  2) Actual output that doesnt work,  3) Expected output showing desired output.  4)If getting Error, then which line of code fails....  Without 1,2,3,4  we would be guessing in the dark for a long time.

Comment: Your `call Macro2` is not within a loop, so it will send one mail only.

Comment: Thanks for this 

I just sorted this out now I am having a problem and I cannot change the filter with Column (T) 

I've changed the above to the below, and I am getting an error 

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$T$480").AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:= _
        cel.Value